# What is the opposite of "RedirectMatch 403 \="

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am running WP with WP Security and it adds this to the htaccess file:

RedirectMatch 403 \=

I understand what it does. But i am running another app on the server that needs to have "=" in the url(imagenames to be specific).

How do i make an exception for \= so it is allowed and not given 403
Can't figure it out.

If it helps the other app is in /photostore/  so anything under that may use = in filenames

thanks

/J

Comment: Well if it's an image name the `=` should be encoded to `%3D`. `myimage=.jpg` would become `myimage%3D.jpg`, the rule should not be applied to this url

Comment: I a still needing to find a solution for this. basically on one line the plugins inserts: RedirectMatch 403 \=
but further down in htaccess i want to undo it manually